# What is the HTML5 equivalent to the align attribute in table cells?

Tags: css, html

I'm refactoring an old site, and that maze is full of tables.
We're moving to HTML5 and I need to fix a table full of

```
<td align="center">
```

code.
I found a partial solution by creating a class

```
.centered {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and assigning it to every TD containing text.
But this is not working on images and some other elements.

```
margin: auto;
```

won't work either.
What's the fastest way to center ALL content inside a TD?

Comment: width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; that should center all content in a div.

Comment: If you are reworking your site “moving to HTML5”, then maybe you should abandon _table layouts_ as well while you’re at it …

Comment: can you show us in a jsFiddle where it's "not working"?

Comment: @SpYk3HH Maybe they're assigning the style to the image instead of the image's container.

Comment: you may need to make "display: inline;" for those images and other elements inside the td

Comment: CBroe is right though; you should consider using tables only where needed.

Comment: Refactoring an old site is generally unproductive, or has negative productivity. You will encounter many problems like this, and what do you expect to achieve?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela If it was a site saying "this page best viewed with Netscape 4.0.3" it might just be possible to salvage it enough to be viewable with other browsers today.

Comment: It's probably faster to build the layout from scratch using HTML 5 if it contains tables for the layout. But you could always use the new `<div style="display: table;"></div>` After all, *The purpose of the `<table>` element is to display tabular data. So, do not use tables for your page layout!*

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If they're block level elements they won't be affected by `text-align: center;`. Someone may have set `img { display: block; }` and that's throwing it out of whack. You can try:

```
td { text-align: center; }
td * { display: inline; }
```

and if it looks as desired you **should definitely** replace * with the desired elements like:

```
td img, td foo { display: inline; }
```

Comment: I would suggest using direct child selection like `td  *` as he may have elements deeper in ment to align or display differently

Comment: If the elements still need to be blocks, then inline-block would be another option.

Comment: Warning: if there are nested tables in the tables, using `td * {display:inline}` will totally wreck your site.

Comment: Very good point. I'll replace "you can replace" with "you should definitely replace".

Comment: OK, everything should be working now, thanks to all of you. On a side note, some programmers still think that tables are fine when you need to display data, and that's my case. This should grant more compatibility with old browsers, that why we stick to tables at the moment.

Comment: A table is the correct thing to use for tabular data no matter what anyone says. As for your worry for older browsers: It's probably useless to worry, but I don't have any data for your site to back it up.

Answer (score 12):

You can use inline css : 
`<td style = "text-align: center;">`

Answer (score 5):

According to the HTML5 CR, which requires continued support to “obsolete” features, too, the `align=center` attribute is rather tricky. [Rendering rules for tables say](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#tables): `td` elements with that attribute “are expected to center text within themselves, as if they had their 'text-align' property set to 'center' in a presentational hint, and to align descendants to the center.”

And aligning descendants is defined as so that a browser will “align only those descendants that have both their 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' properties computing to a value other than 'auto', that are over-constrained and that have one of those two margins with a used value forced to a greater value, and that do not themselves have an applicable align attribute. When multiple elements are to align a particular descendant, the most deeply nested such element is expected to override the others. Aligned elements are expected to be aligned by having the used values of their left and right margins be set accordingly.”

So it really depends on the content.

Comment: Whoa. I didn't know you were on Stack Overflow. I will be reading through your answers all morning now. =)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code as replacement for table align

```
table 
{
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: The OP was asking for TD alignment.

Answer (score -3):

Add this code into your StyleSheet:

```
margin-top:80px;
```

Comment: How does this solve OPs question? He wants to centre text, and you are telling him how to move it vertically.